# How to draw a circle with x mark?

Tags: wpf, pathgeometry

I'm trying to draw a circle with perfect X mark. 
I managed to draw a circle with half of the X mark. I'm not sure how to draw the second half.

Thank you

```
 <Path Stroke="Black"
          StrokeThickness="4" Fill="Red" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathGeometry.Figures>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="0,0">
                        <PathFigure.Segments>
                          <LineSegment Point="100,100" />
                            <ArcSegment Size="50,50"
                                        RotationAngle="45"
                                        IsLargeArc="True"
                                        SweepDirection="Clockwise"
                                        Point="0,0" />
                            <ArcSegment Size="50,50"
                                        RotationAngle="45"
                                        IsLargeArc="True"
                                        SweepDirection="Clockwise"
                                        Point="100,100" />
                        </PathFigure.Segments>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry.Figures>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "simplify" this, or at least make it take up less space in the XAML editor, by [using Path Markup Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293(v=vs.110).aspx). The portion of `Data` before the blank line reproduces what you've already got: `M` for "move", `L` for "line to", `A` for "arc". The "`M`ove" and "`L`ine To" commands after the blank line add the second line.

```
<Path
    Stroke="Black"
    StrokeThickness="4"
    Fill="Red"
    Data="
        M 0,0 
        L 100,100
        A 50,50 45 1 1 0,0 
        A 50,50 45 1 1 100,100 

        M 100,0 
        L 0,100"
    />
```

You don't need to format it with newlines like that; I just inserted the newlines to clarify how it maps onto your version. Fortunately, you added the attributes to your `ArcSegment` elements in the same order as the corresponding arguments to `A` in the markup syntax.

This is how it's usually done, though it's arguably less readable:

```
Data="M 0,0 L 100,100 A 50,50 45 1 1 0,0 A 50,50 45 1 1 100,100 M 100,0 L 0,100"
```

---

**Alternatively**, to finish it the same way you started, just add the second line as another `PathFigure`:

```
<Path 
    Stroke="Black"
    StrokeThickness="4" 
    Fill="Red" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry.Figures>
                <PathFigure StartPoint="0,0">
                    <PathFigure.Segments>
                        <LineSegment Point="100,100" />
                        <ArcSegment 
                            Size="50,50"
                            RotationAngle="45"
                            IsLargeArc="True"
                            SweepDirection="Clockwise"
                            Point="0,0" 
                            />
                        <ArcSegment 
                            Size="50,50"
                            RotationAngle="45"
                            IsLargeArc="True"
                            SweepDirection="Clockwise"
                            Point="100,100" 
                            />
                    </PathFigure.Segments>
                </PathFigure>

                <!-- Second line -->
                <PathFigure StartPoint="100,0">
                    <PathFigure.Segments>
                        <LineSegment Point="0,100" />
                    </PathFigure.Segments>
                </PathFigure>
                <!-- /Second line -->

            </PathGeometry.Figures>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this...https://materialdesignicons.com/

```
<Viewbox Width="48" Height="48">
<Canvas Width="24" Height="24">
    <Path Data="M12,20C7.59,20 4,16.41 4,12C4,7.59 7.59,4 12,4C16.41,4 20,7.59 20,12C20,16.41 16.41,20 12,20M12,2C6.47,2 2,6.47 2,12C2,17.53 6.47,22 12,22C17.53,22 22,17.53 22,12C22,6.47 17.53,2 12,2M14.59,8L12,10.59L9.41,8L8,9.41L10.59,12L8,14.59L9.41,16L12,13.41L14.59,16L16,14.59L13.41,12L16,9.41L14.59,8Z" Fill="Black" />
</Canvas>
```